# extjs grid hide and show changes width

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, grid

I have a extjs grid simple stuff within a div. I hide and show that container by clicking a button. after hiding the container, if I resize the window, and then again show the 
container, the grid gets a width of 100px. I would expect it to make use of width:100%

Comment: try adding `hideMode: "offsets"` to the grid config or possibly the containing panel's config. EXT is funny this way.

Comment: I think that would work, only if I hide grid with ext methods ? right now I am just hiding parent by literally making visibility:hidden .. not sure why grid is recomputing it's dimensions when it is hidden

Comment: I think EXT listens for window resize events, then does layout on everything. If your grid is hidden when that happens, it doesn't layout properly. Can you call doLayout() on the grid after showing it? I'm guessing at this point btw...

Comment: yeah doLayout() is an option, but my grid is nested pretty deep. so I don't have a direct handle to it. right now it works perfectly if grid is visible and i resize window

Answer (score 0):

```
.container{
   border:1px solid gold;
 }
.row{
   padding:20px;
}
.col4{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  padding:20px;
  font-size:20px;
  background-color:red;
  color:#fff;
  }

 </style>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
       $(".container .thrd-row").css("display","none");
});
 $(window).resize(function(){
     $(".container .thrd-row").removeAttr("style");
 });
});


</script>
  //use html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row firs-row">
        <div class="col4">1</div>
        <div class="col4">1</div>
        <div class="col4">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row second-row">
        <div class="col4">1</div>
        <div class="col4">1</div>
        <div class="col4">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row thrd-row">
        <div class="col4">1</div>
        <div class="col4">1</div>
        <div class="col4">1</div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn">click hide</button>
</div>
```